# VbScript: get the server status using "Adodb.Stream"

Tags: vbscript, stream, connection

How do I get the status from a Shoutcast streamming server using VbScript?
The closer I got was this:

```
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.partyvibe.com:8010", False
xHttp.Send
with bStrm
    .type = 1 'binary
    .open
    msgbox xHttp.responseBody
    msgbox .state
end with
```

But it actually doesn't work because the stream never finish 'opening', it is a continuous radio stream.

I'd like to retrieve only the few first bytes of the stream to know the server response.
(eg.: the server is out, the server is streaming ok, timeout, ...)

http://www.partyvibe.com:8010

It also may not be a Shoutcast server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
Const TIMEOUT = 5000
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Dim url: url = "http://www.partyvibe.com:8010"

xHttp.Open "GET", url, True
xHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Winamp/5.x"
xHttp.Send

WScript.sleep TIMEOUT


If (xHttp.readyState<>3) then
    msgbox "Stream server is not responding!"
end if
```

.readyState refrence:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

- (1) LOADING --------> time out exceeded
- (4) COMPLETED ------> should not be completed if the server still streamming